# urlFetchApp quota and redirection

Tags: google-apps-script

My question is about the quota of URL fetched per day using urlFetchApp in Google Apps Script.

When a fetched URL automatically redirects to another URL using the "location" HTTP argument, does this count for 2 fetches or only 1 ?

Thanks

Thierry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fair question. Redirects will NOT count against your total number of UrlFetch calls per day.