# Is Docs Plugin UrlFetchApp quota per user or per plugin?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is Docs Plugin UrlFetchApp quota per user or per plugin?

Seems like a per plugin quota would dramatically curtail the number of users.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, it is per user. Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875014/how-does-daily-google-apps-script-quota-limit-apply?rq=1).

To know more about the Quotas in Google Apps Script, this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) is the lists of the daily quotas as of April 2014. You can confirm the current on the Quota Limits tab of the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/a/google.com/dashboard). Just take note that this list of quotas are subject to elimination, reduction, or change at any time, without notice.

For more information, also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195150/urlfetchapp-quota-and-redirection?rq=1).